# Redis: Will set override setex on a key?

Tags: redis

If I set a key that has an expiry using `setex`, and later update the value of that key with `set`, will the `set` remove the expiry property?

`setex testKey 10 val123`

5 seconds later...

`set testKey val456`

Comment: Better then asking this simple question, you can spend lesser time with `Redis-cli` which will better help you to understand these type of basic cases :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the expiration/timeout will be removed.

If you want to keep the timeout, you have to use `TTL` command to get the remaining time-to-live, and call `SETEX` to reset both the value and timeout.

In order to make these two operations atomic, you can wrap them into a Lua script.

Also, you can use `PTTL` and `PSETEX` to get milliseconds precision.